Some keys do not work
27" Retina iMac, with the Apple keyboard. All of a sudden, some keys do not work anymore when logged in to the system (specifically O,L,K,M). Surprisingly, they work when doing the log-in, so it should not be a hardware fault. Any idea on what I should look into?

Boot into Safe Mode and see if the problem continues

Did you, by chance, spill liquid on the keyboard? It also could be some non-liquid substance like food crumbs, fine sand or dust. If it could be the latter, turn the keyboard upside-down and tap the edge (gently) against a hard surface.

@Allan I'll try.

@IconDaemon: don't think that's the problem, they keys work fine in the login

See if this fits:  https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250006675

@TomGewecke it was exactly this, thanks!
